# Connecting to Local Computers with Wireguard

Tags: networking, router, vpn, firewall, wireguard

I have been setting  up a Wireguard VPN network to access computers on a local network. The  LAN I need access to created by an EdgeRouter X (v1.10.9) who's WAN  connection is provided by a larger network which I cannot port forward  or control. To circumvent this, I setup a remote server (VPS/Droplet) running  Wireguard, and plan on connecting both the EdgeRouter and remote clients  to that.
I am able to connect both the EdgeRouter and remote  client (my laptop) to the server successfully, but cannot access the  computers behind the router. I have been roughly following this guide: https://gist.github.com/insdavm/b1034635ab23b8839bf957aa406b5e39
Looking at my configuration below, what do I need to change? My local network is 10.10.1.1 and my VPN is 10.10.2.1.

Server Wireguard config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.2.1/24
PrivateKey = <private server key>
ListenPort = 51820

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wgo -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# EdgeRouter
[Peer]
    PublicKey = <public router key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.10.2.2/32, 10.10.1.0/24
# laptop
[Peer]
    PublicKey = <public laptop key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.10.2.3/32
```

Laptop Wireguard config:

```
[Interface]
    PrivateKey = <private laptop key>
    ListenPort = 51820
    Address = 10.10.2.3/24

[Peer]
    PublicKey = <public server key>
    AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.0/16
    Endpoint = <public server ip>:51820
    PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Router Wireguard Config:

```
configure
edit interfaces wireguard wg0
set address 10.10.2.2/24
set listen-port 51820
set route-allowed-ips true

set peer <public server key> endpoint <public server ip>:51820
set peer <public server key> allowed-ips 10.10.2.1
set peer <public server key> allowed-ips 10.10.0.0/16
set peer <public server key> persistent-keepalive 25
set private-key <private router key>
exit
commit
save
exit
```

The router also has a firewall rule in WAN_LOCAL which allows  51820/udp. The server also has a firewall but 51820/udp is allowed.
Again,  both the router and laptop connect and can ping 10.10.2.1, but neither  can ping each other and the laptop cannot ping anything on the  10.10.1.0/24 range.

Please let me know if you need more information, and thank you!